Demon movie early 1990's or late 1980's
I saw this film roughly probably around 1999, but the look of the film was earlier.More like films made around 1990. It was on daytime TV. Possibly Lifetime or WE. So, American or Canadian.
At any rate, it was about this woman who moved into a house that was occupied by an entity. It kept harassing the family, no matter what she did. So, she left the family and thus taking the demon with her to go live in a paranormal investigation center. I remember the room she was kept in was white with a glass wall. The entity kept appearing as a big black cloud thing. She lived at the center for awhile until another one of the researchers messed up the project. I don't remember how the movie ended.
It was a pretty good rip-off of The Entity with Barbara Hershey. For some time, I thought it was The Haunted, but after seeing it recently, it is definitely not the correct film.

Is it The Atticus Instititute (1985)?

The Atticus Institute was made in 2015. The movie I am looking for, I watched in the early 1990's. Thanks for trying.
